# Clear all options from select and change it

Tags: jquery

If the dropdown menu change from Ophalen to Bezorgen then I want to change the options from the next dropdown menu if they change it back from Bezorgen to Ophalen the old veriables needs to be come back.

so I tried to delete all options and fill the select with new options. but they don't be deleted and the new options didn't show when I change the other dropdown menu.

my code:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#bezorgkosten', function(e) {
      var target = $('#bezorgkosten :selected').text();
      if (target == 'Ophalen') {
        var ophalen = [{
          val: '0.00',
          text: 'a'
        }, {
          val: '0.00',
          text: 'b'
        }];
        $('option', '#betaalmethode').clear();

        $(ophalen).each(function() {
          $('#betaalmethode').append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
        });
      }


      if (target == 'Bezorgen' || 'Bezorgen op ander adres') {
        var bezorgen = [{
          val: '0.00',
          text: 'IDEAL'
        }, {
          val: '1.50',
          text: 'PayPal'
        }, {
          val: '2.45',
          text: 'CreditCard'
        }];
        $('option', '#betaalmethode').remove();

        $(bezorgen).each(function() {
          $('#betaalmethode').append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
        });
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='bezorgkosten'>
  <option value='0.00'>Ophalen</option>
  <option value='<?= $s_BezorgKosten ?>'>Bezorgen</option>
  <option value='<?= $s_BezorgKosten ?>'>Bezorgen op ander adres</option>
</select>

<select id='betaalmethode'>

</select>
```

Only it dont work for me on JsFiddle, because the first 3 options didnt come @JsFiddle but at my website it shows.

Comment: Can you please try to make a jsFiddle ?

Comment: @Brewal added! only it dont work for me and dont understand where i need to put my jquery.

Comment: You can't do it here. Use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Brewal got the same problem if i added in jsfiddle. if im doing `$('#betaalmethode').remove();` then the select box will be deleted so it works but i want only to delete the options. do you know how to do? i tried mutch on stackoverflow but that didnt work for me.

Comment: Ok... [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/khqkszaf/). You have an error in console because of the `.clear()` method you use. It does not natively exists. Did you want to use `.remove()` instead ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line actually ? `$('option', '#betaalmethode').clear();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3jwdw3np/1/

I have two select boxes. When you change the first one, the second select box changes based on the variable `arr`.

You will need to use `$('#two').html("");` to clear whichever select box before appending new options.

A quick explanation of the `$(arr).each`

```
$(arr).each(function (index, item) {
    // make a new option element
    var option = $('<option>');

    // add the attribute and text to the option
    option.attr('value', item.val).text(item.text);

    // append the option to the second select box
    $('#two').append(option);
});
```

Maybe this will work for you?

EDIT:

If you want two options to produce the same results then you could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/3jwdw3np/2/

Notice the second if statement:

`if (this.value == 'Option 2 || this.value == 'Option 3')`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your mistake came from here :

```
$('option', '#betaalmethode').clear();
```

It triggers an error since `.clear()` method is not part of jQuery. Just use `.remove()` as you have done farther in your code :

```
$('option', '#betaalmethode').remove();
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mj7dndj1/)**